# MatMomentDateModule display format

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, date-format

I have an Angular 6 app with Angular Material. I want to implement Material Datepicker with custom date format (since not everyone lives in the US), I've managed to change locale by usage of `MatMomentDateModule`. However, I have a value like this `1.2.2018` meanwhile I need to display `01.02.2018`. How do I change date format? I haven't found any docs about this(when using moment.js date adapter).

Comment: Did you look at DatePipe with `format` method? https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

You might have added something like this to the picker

```
    export const MY_FORMATS = {
        parse: {
            dateInput: 'L'
        },
        display: {
            dateInput: 'L',
            monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
            dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
            monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
        }
    };

@Component({
providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
      useValue: MY_FORMATS
    }
 ]
})
```

use this to get the output as "MM/DD/YYYY"
refer https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ to see all available formats